# c++ Function that allocates memory and fills a buffer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, buffer

Hello I'm trying to read/write my own file formats to learn about c++. I've figured out the reading and writing part with fstream so far, but when extracting my code into seperate functions I've ran into some trouble.

Maybe it's my expectations that are wrong, but here is how I intended to handle it.

**Main Function**

```cpp
int main()
{
  const char* path = "path/to/file.dat";

  // this pointer should be changed to the pointer referencing the heap(?) allocated 
  // buffer inside the function 'readFromFile'
  char* buffer;

  // How can I pass the buffer in a way that sets the pointer to the buffer in
  // this scope to the pointer that is created and allocated inside this function?
  int bufferSize = readFromFile(path, buffer);

  // log colour data to console
  for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += 4)
  {
    std::cout << "rgba(" 
      << buffer[i] << ", "
      << buffer[i + 1] << ", "
      << buffer[i + 2] << ", "
      << buffer[i + 3] << ")" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**ReadFromFile Function**

```cpp
// also tried 'char* &buffer'
int readFromFile(const char* path, char* buffer)
}
  // read and parse the file header...
  // this contains the rgba data size

  // allocate data for the buffer based on the header information
  buffer = new char[header.DataLength];

  // fill the buffer with data from the file
  fs.read(buffer, header.DataLength);
  
  // reading is sucessful
  // buffer in this scope is filled

  return header.DataLength;
}
```

Two ways I found to pass a pointer by reference are:

```cpp
char* buffer;

readFromFile(x, &buffer);
int readFromFile(x, char** buffer);

readFromFile(x, buffer);
int readFromFile(x, char* &buffer); //is what I ended up going with
```

I'm quite new to c++ so memory management and pointers are fairly foreign concepts to me. I'm pretty sure my problem is a standard one, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: parameters are bassed by value in C++. Pointers are no exception to this. `buffer = new char[header.DataLength];` assigns to a function local variable called `buffer` that is gone when the function returns. If you want to modify the argument passed to the function you need to pass it by reference

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from? Is it the chapter that explains passing parameters to functions by value versus by reference? If not, what is it? Do you know what references are, in C++, and how to use them? It seems that you're missing some core C++ fundamentals, which should be explained in every C++ textbook. "To learn C++" -- the only realistic way to do so is with a good textbook that explains the core principles of the most complicated and hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today.

Comment: simpler example same effect `void foo(int x) { x = 42; }`

Comment: If you have a buffer of raw bytes I suggest you use `std::vector<std::byte>` (or alternatively `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`) instead of separate `char*` and `int` pair.

Comment: To be clear, a pointer is a variable that holds an address. It's handled just like every other variable and passed by value. You can use a pointer to pass a pointed-at object by reference, but the the pointer itself is passed by value.

Comment: Ideally, use a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. If you insist heavily on managing your own dynamic allocation, use a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` buffer. Your future self will thank you. A raw `new` keyword is rarely a good idea. It may be needed in dynamic linked structures where smart pointers could cause stack overflows, but that is _not_ the case here.

Comment: Both of the things you tried should have compiled and worked, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: See, for example, [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf3677831239b989).

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-code I ended up writing was correct as @molbdnilo pointed out, but in my actual project I accidentally mixed both the aproaches.

old code:

```cpp
char* buffer;

readFromFile(x, &buffer);
int readFromFile(x, char*& buffer);
```

which my compiler responded to with: `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

Check the last code block in my question to see what ended up working.

Thanks for the quick replies everyone!